# Is every bounded operator part of a $C_0$-semigroup?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ be a bounded linear operator on $X$. Is there necessarily a $C_0$-semigroup $T$ such that $B = T(t)$ for some $t$? There might be something obvious I'm missing, but I'm not sure of a good way to approach this problem. The most obvious idea to me would be using some sort of functional calculus for bounded operators that lets you apply a logarithm, and would hopefully result in a (not necessarily bounded) generator for the desired semigroup. I am not aware of any such functional calculus though. I also can't think of a trivial "natural exponential progression" from the identity map to $B$. As far as counter examples go, I know of few theorems that force specific behaviors of $C_0$-semigroups. An obvious one to try is the $0$ operator. At least on $X = C_0[0,1)$, though, the translation semigroup is nilpotent. This is not a homework problem or anything, just something I got curious about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A simple counterexample:**

A very easy way to get a counterexample is to consider any finite dimensional space $X \not= \{0\}$. Then every $C_0$-semigroup is given by a matrix exponential function, and thus, every operator that occurs in a $C_0$-semigroup is necessarily invertible.

So just take $B$ to be any non-invertible operator on a finite dimensional space.

**A general reference on the question:**

[This article](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00013-009-3154-x) ([link to arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2419)) by Tanja Eisner deals precisely with the question when a given operator can be embedded into a $C_0$-semigroup.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is the generator of a bounded $C_0$ semigroup $T(t)$, then the spectrum of $A$ must lie in the closed left-hand plane $\Re\lambda > 0$ because the resolvent of $A$ is given by the following for $\Re\lambda > 0$:
$$
            \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}T(t)xdt=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}e^{tA}xdt=e^{t(A-\lambda I)}(A-\lambda I)^{-1}x|_{t=0}^{\infty}=(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x.
$$
Obviously this is a heuristic argument, but the result is true for all $\Re\lambda >0$. Furthermore, if $M$ is a uniform norm bound for $T$, then
$$
               \|(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\| \le \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\Re\lambda t}dtM\|x\|=\frac{M}{\Re\lambda}\|x\|,\;\;\; \Re\lambda > 0.
$$
So the generator of a bounded $C_0$ semigroup has a resolvent estimate that does not hold for general operators. This type of estimate precludes having a generator $A$ that is nilpotent, for example. To see why, suppose $A^n=0$ for some $n > 1$. Then the following would fail to satisfy the required estimate given above:
$$
           (\lambda I-A)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-\frac{1}{\lambda}A)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(I+\frac{1}{\lambda}A + \frac{1}{\lambda^2} A^2 + \cdots+\frac{1}{\lambda^{n-1}}A^{n-1}\right).
$$
By the same token, $A$ cannot have any vector $x\ne 0$ in the domain of $A$ for which $A^nx=0$. So, while the resolvent estimate for $A$ may seem innocuous, it is not. Nilpotent vectors generally keep operators from having all positive roots; however, if $\lambda > 0$, then all positive powers of $(\lambda I-A)$ are defined for generators of a $C_0$ semigroup through the functional calculus. To see why, note that
$$
           \int_0^{\infty}t^{-1+r}e^{-t}dt = \Gamma(r),\;\; r > 0.
$$
By a change of variable for $s > 0$,
$$
    \int_0^{\infty}(st)^{-1+r}e^{-st}d(st)
          = s^{r}\int_0^{\infty}u^{-1+r}e^{-u}du = s^{r}\Gamma(r)
$$
In this way, one may define the following at least on a dense domain:
$$
                A^r = \frac{1}{\Gamma(r)}\int_0^{\infty}u^{-1+r}e^{-u}T(u)du
$$
You can't do this with a general nilpotent operator $A$. Generators of $C_0$ semigroups can be used with a functional calculus that is derived from the Laplace transform, and is related to time evolution systems, which is what the transform was invented for in the first place.

Comment: I'm rather confused here. I don't see why the finite von Neumann sum prevents the resolvent estimate. I'm also not sure I'm following the motivation of the functional calculus. We're essentially trying to replace $s$ by $A$, correct? I would then expect $A^r \Gamma(r)$ to be "defined" as the left integral with $s$ replaced by $A$ and $e^{-st}$ by $T(-t)$ (which clearly doesn't work as a definition). I don't really see the link to the representation given. Lastly, while that's some interesting stuff, the connection to my question went over my head as well.

Comment: @Vormanax : The problem is the behavior near $\lambda=0$. That's where the problems arise.

Comment: @Vormanax : The resolvent estimate comes from $R(\lambda)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t}T(t)dt$. However, if you look at the resolvent for a nilpotent operator of order $n > 1$ (which you can get by a simple resolvent expansion,) there are higher order terms $1/\lambda^n$ that will not give the desired estimate near $\lambda=0$. The desired estimate of the resolvent for $\lambda$ near $0$ is a necessary consequence of having a bounded $C_0$ semigroup. I know ... I did my best to summarize the main features of the theory, but there's a lot in there, and I know of no way to distill it further.

Comment: I'm familiar with the Hille-Yoshida Lemma and elementary aspects regarding the theory, so I'm aware of the resolvent estimate itself. I did expect there to be an argument regarding the higher order terms around 0, but I don't see how to guarantee that the powers of $A$ don't interfere with this. I imagine it will have to do with $\lambda$ being in the resolvent set, so $A$ will not be "strong enough" to counteract it.

Comment: @Vormanax : Take any $x$ for which $A^{n-1}x\ne 0$. You'll be able to bound the other terms away, compare to this one, as $\lambda\rightarrow 0$. Multiply by $\lambda^{n-1}$ and let $\lambda\rightarrow 0$, if you are more comfortable with that.

Comment: Right, of course. Thanks.

Comment: @Vormanax : If my answer is acceptable to you, please check the mark next to my answer. You can +1 it optionally, too.

Comment: As I said before, while the stuff you wrote about is interesting, I don't see how it answers my question. Do you suppose that the functional calculus you mention at the end lets us construct a semigroup $T$ such that $T(t) = B$ for some $t$? If so, I don't see how one would. It is in fact defined on a generator of a specific $C_0$-semigroup, but I'm looking to find one with a certain property. Does your construction provide a counter example? This seems more likely, but again I don't see how. You talk about restrictions on the generator, not about the values of $T$.

Comment: @Vormanax Can $B=T(t)$ be nilpotent? Can $B$ have an eigenvalue $0$? Can $B$ have an eigenvalue $\lambda > 1$? Etc.

Comment: Can $B = T(t)$ be nilpotent? Yes. Let $X = C_0[0,1) = \{f \in C[0,1) : f(t) \to 0$ for $t \to 1\}$. Let $(T(t)f)(s) = f(t+s)$ if $t + s < 1$ and $0$ else. This is a $C_0$-semigroup which satisfies $T(1/2)^2 f = T(1)f = 0$, thus it is nilpotent (and as such also has eigenvalue 0). Can it have eigenvalue $\lambda > 1$? Let $X = C[0,1]$ and $T(t)f = e^{t} f$. Then $T(2)f$ = $e^2 f$ with $e^2 > 1$. Just because the generator can't have certain properties doesn't mean that the semigroup can't.

Comment: @Vormanax : $T(t)=T(t/n)^n$. Every element of the semigroup has arbitrary positive roots. You can't do that with just any operator.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, thanks.